# MySQL combine results from two tables with flag

Tags: mysql

Hello i am trying to solve this issue tru MYSQl without additional server side code.

1.event

```
+--------------------------+-------------------+
|id                        | online_payee_id   |   
+--------------------------+-------------------+
| 1                        | 110               |
| 2                        | 330               |
|44 (not in charity table) | 330               |
+---+------------------------------------------+
```

2.charity

```
+---+------------+------------+
|id | event_id   |  payee_id  |
+---+------------+------------+
| 1 | 1          |    330     |
| 2 | 2          |    330     |
+---+------------+------------+
```

what i want is union this two tables into a new table  with a flag indicating "isEvent" and "Charity payee"  OR "Event payee & Charity payee" for example:

Note online_payee & payee_id are basically same field.

```
+---+------------+----------------------------+
|id | event_id   |    flag                    |
+---+------------+----------------------------+
| 1 | 1          | Charity payee              |
| 1 | 2          | Event payee & Charity payee|
| 2 | 44         | IsEvent                    |
+---+------------+----------------------------+
```

I have tried something like this but getting dupe results.

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(EV.id, EV2.id) AS `id`, 
IF(EV.online_payee_id AND EC.payee_id,"Event payee / Charity payee",  
  IF(EV.online_payee_id,"Event payee","Charity payee")) 
AS `type` 
FROM `payee` AS `P` 
LEFT JOIN `event` AS `EV` ON P.id = EV.online_payee_id 
LEFT JOIN `charity` AS `EC` ON P.id = EC.payee_id
LEFT JOIN `event` AS `EV2` ON EC.event_id = EV2.id 
WHERE (P.id = 330) 
AND (EC.payee_id IS NOT NULL OR EV.online_payee_id IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: there is FROM `payee` AS `P`

Comment: any ideas? Maybe something with UNION?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add the payee table to the sample data. It may not make a difference though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To query two tables and create a flag that describes the type of record based on the tables information is located in, and search for records related to one account identification:

```
SELECT event_id, online_payee_id payee_id, type
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT event.id event_id,
    IF (charity.event_id, "charity", "event") type
  FROM event
  LEFT JOIN charity ON event.id = charity.event_id
) events
LEFT JOIN event ON events.event_id = event.id
WHERE online_payee_id = 330
;
```

Outputs:

| event_id | payee_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 330 | charity |
| 44 | 330 | event |

The `WHERE online_payee_id = 330` clause restricts results to records associated with payee identification "330".

---

*The details...*

Given tables:

payee:

| id |
| --- |
| 110 |
| 220 |
| 330 |

event:

| id | online_payee_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 110 |
| 2 | 220 |
| 2 | 330 |
| 44 | 330 |

charity:

| id | event_id | payee_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 110 |
| 2 | 2 | 330 |

The query:

```
SELECT event_id, online_payee_id payee_id, type
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT event.id event_id,
    IF (charity.event_id, "charity", "event") type
  FROM event
  LEFT JOIN charity ON event.id = charity.event_id
) events
LEFT JOIN event ON events.event_id = event.id
/*WHERE online_payee_id = 330*/
;
```

...(without the restricting `WHERE` clause) outputs:

| event_id | payee_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 110 | charity |
| 2 | 330 | charity |
| 2 | 220 | charity |
| 44 | 330 | event |

First creating an ad hoc, temporary table, named `events`, that [`LEFT JOIN`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx)s the `event` and `charity` tables. Using [`DISTINCT`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx) to create a table that contains a list of unique events. Also using [`IF`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-statement/) which a check of the existence of a corresponding value in the `charity` table to determine whether it is a charitable event or not.

```
SELECT DISTINCT event.id event_id,
  IF (charity.event_id, "charity", "event") type
FROM event
LEFT JOIN charity ON event.id = charity.event_id
;
```

Temporary table output:

| event_id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | charity |
| 2 | charity |
| 44 | event |

Next naming the temporary table `events` and `LEFT JOIN`ing it with the `event` table, to get the `payee_id` information.

```
SELECT event_id, online_payee_id payee_id, type
FROM ( /* temporary table query goes here */ ) events
LEFT JOIN event ON events.event_id = event.id
;
```

The result is a list of unique `event_id`/`payee_id` combinations, and if the event is charitable.

---

```
-- create
CREATE TABLE payee (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE event (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  online_payee_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE charity (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  event_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  payee_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO payee VALUES (110), (220), (330);
INSERT INTO event VALUES (1, 110), (2, 220), (2, 330), (44, 330);
INSERT INTO charity VALUES (1, 1, 110), (2, 2, 330);

-- fetch 
SELECT event_id, online_payee_id payee_id, type
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT event.id event_id,
    IF (charity.event_id, "charity", "event") type
  FROM event
  LEFT JOIN charity ON event.id = charity.event_id
) events
LEFT JOIN event ON events.event_id = event.id
;
```

Try it here: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3ygkeqb59

Comment: Thank you sir, but i am looking results for specific payee for an example 330, so 110 won't be in result set.

Comment: Accomplishing your requirement is a easy as adding `WHERE online_payee_id = 330` to the end of the query. My answer is updated, and further explained for everyone who wishes to know how it works.

Comment: Tnx please vote up, came up with another solution with union and subquery but this one works as well.